# The use of gerund in a given sentence

Tags: gerunds

Let us consider this sentence, comparing Latin and Greek languages :

"They have many formal similarities, both depending a good deal on endings"

1)Why did we use a gerund (depending) here? Can we use a verb (depend) instead? How will the meaning change?

2)Is the word "endings" a gerund here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses a gerund because it is a gerund clause, modifying the whole sentence. If you used a finite verb, this would be an independent clause, and would need either to be a separate sentence, or be linked with a suitable conjunction.

*Ending* is a noun which is derived from a gerund, but it does not mean "an act of ending" as a gerund would. It means "the particular sequence of sounds with which a form of a word ends".

Comment: Can I say: "They have many formal similarities, that both depend a good deal on endings", instead?

Comment: @XY: I find that a bit awkward, perhaps because it is not quite clear what the role of the _that_ clause is in the sentence; but I think it is grammatical.

Comment: Suppose it is: "They have many formal similarities, both depend a good deal on endings"... (without that). What will it be?

Comment: @XY: that would be a [run-on sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_(fused)_sentences)

Comment: Ok, I am very grateful to you. Only the last question: there are a lot of words that end with "ing", but they are not gerunds, what types can they be? If you know them (the types), please cite them to me.

Comment: Could you please answer me?

Comment: No, @XY, I am not. In the first place, that is something for you to research. Secondly, this is a volunteer site. The fact that I answered your original question, and even agreed to answer two subsidiary questions does not commit me to answering any question you might think of asking.

Comment: Okaaay chill out man :-D